# Is there a way to queue a function call and its parameters for later calling?

Tags: c#, function, parameters

Is there a way to store function calls and their variable parameters to a database while the player is offline and call them again when the player turns back online.

Hi! I am working on a new game(unity c#), that has the player walking through areas with little reception. The player finds codewords and enters them into a field to unlock content. Meanwhile I want to log the triggered codewords for each user. The problem is the connection might get lost during a session. I managed to queue the functions for each Time the player enters codeword while disconnected, but after getting reception again the player only sends the last entry. 
Help is much appreciated!

```
public void NotConnected()
{
        CallsOnQueue.Add( () => StartCoroutine(TestCodeword())); 
}

public void BackOnline()
{
        if (CallsOnQueue.Count == 0)
        {
            LookforCodewordInDB();
        }    
        else
        {
            foreach (Action item in Callsonqueue)
                StartCoroutine(TestCodeword(teamname, codeword, city, date));

        }
        Callsonqueue.Clear();
}
```

Comment: are you using LiteDB?

Comment: i am using a mysqldb

Comment: Always put the commands and parameters in a queue and have a looping thread send them. The looping thread should send the message and on successfully sending the command remove it from the queue.

Comment: Did you try the __debugger__?? Always do that __before__ coming here!!

Answer (score -1):

I think the most sensed approach is to store the function as an object in the database, then later retrieve it.

```
public class MyFunction{
     string FuncionName { get; set; }
     public string Param1 { get; set; }
     public string Param2 { get; set; }
     //more params
}
```

then you could use a comparison operator to invoke the appropriate method.

```
switch (storedFunction.FunctionName)
{
     case "myFunction":
         myFunction();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that your code is fine except for your foreach loop.

Instead of invoking the stored action, you are starting the same coroutine for each element!

Change your code to this

```
foreach (Action item in Callsonqueue)
                item.Invoke():
```